# Change Default system encoding from UTF-8 to iso-8859-1, WINDOWS

Tags: asp.net, windows, powershell, vb6, encoding

En la empresa tenemos una aplicación antigua en VB6 que funciona solo con el encoding iso-8859-1 y es llamada desde otras aplicaciones en NET y NET CORE.
Si colocamos la aplicación en una máquina que tenga System.Text.Encoding UTF-8 por defecto falla al pasar strings de una dll a otra.

Edit:
Desde un aplicativo ASP .NET llamamos unas dll que fueron escritas en VB6 hace mucho tiempo, que tienen los procesos de licencia de los sistemas, estas dll funcionan perfectas en escritorio y cuando el sitio web esta en un servidor windows local con IIS instalado.

El método que llamamos es de la siguiente forma lic.validarLicencia("key", "client");

al momento de ejecutar esto en el contenedor docker, el log muestra que a la DLL vb6 le esta llegando carácteres raros, de esta forma "???????", pero esto solo ocurre con las imagenes docker de windows server core 2019 en adelante del sitio oficial de Microsoft.

Al revisar las diferencias entre  contenedores (en el que funciona y en el que no) vemos que donde funciona tiene el iso-8859-1" mientras que donde NO funciona tiene el encoding por defecto UTF-8.

la cantidad de aplicaciones que tenemos que llaman a estas componentes son considerables, entonces necesito poder cambiar el encoding por defecto a ISO-8859-1.

He de resaltar que no existe entorno gráfico ya que es solo comandos mediante la consola de docker y el dockerfile.

La máquina donde funciona bien, al usar el comando [System.Text.Encoding]::Default retorna lo siguiente.

```
PS C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

y los nuevos servidores donde falla, al correr el mismo comando dice lo siguiente:

```
PS C:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Todo es por linea de comandos, sin entorno grafico, alguien sabe como cambiar el default encoding del sistema a iso-8859-1 vía powershell o cmd?

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente: ejecuta _intl.cpl_, ve a la pestaña Administrativo, pulsa en Cambiar la configuracion regional del sistema y fijate si tienes marcado _Version Beta: use utf-8 unicode para la compatibilidad de idioma en todo el mundo_ Si es asi, quitalo y prueba

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¡No olvides traducir el título! Estamos en [es.so].

Comment: @Pikoh quizá sea esto, hay manera de hacerlo por consola? no tengo acceso al entorno gráfico.

Comment: Pues..no que yo sepa la verdad. Es posible que modifique algo en el registro de windows y si es asi se podría ejecutar un script .reg...pero no se si es asi

Comment: Acabo de ver [esta pagina](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587680/where-can-i-find-34beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worl.html) y la primera respuesta dice como cambiarlo en el registro..pero no se si funcionará o no. Aunque eso es para activarlo. He mirado en mi equipo por curiosidad y los datos serian: ACP: 1252 , OEMCP: 850, MACCP:10000